# Having some weird animation bug using TrailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt to delete cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to simply delete cells with this method of tableView. For some reason, doing so creates this weird animation bug that I can't figure out. Here is my code:

```html
let deleteSubcatAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, handler) in
    print("Delete Subcategory Action Tapped")
    let subcategory = Global.budget.categories[indexPath.section].subcategories[indexPath.row]
    Global.budget.categories[indexPath.section].subcategories.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left) }
    
deleteSubcatAction.backgroundColor = .red
let rowConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteSubcatAction])
return rowConfig
```

When I drag the cell to the left, I see the delete action as I expect and pressing the action calls the method as it should. However, the cell isn't removed from the table. Instead, the actions stay locked in place and the rest of the content of the cell slides back to the right as if I had released my finger without pressing an action. Then, if I tap elsewhere in my app, the actions minimize back to the right, and the cell simply disappears without any sort of removal animation. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUyUo5_sAVc&feature=youtu.be) of the bug I recorded. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that pops out is that you aren't calling the completion handler (in your case, the `handler` property) at the end of your `UIContextualAction` closure. As in, `handler(true)`.

The second thing is that you aren't doing anything to ensure that the action is properly animated in the table view. The non-intrusive way of doing this (without reloading the entire table view from the data source) is by using:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableview.endUpdates()
```

[See the API docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates) for more info.

P.S. Ideally, you should have your data source hooked up to your table view in such a way that the table view reacts to events triggered by observers of your data source, rather than deleting table rows "manually" in response to a UI action.

Comment: Noted, I'll try both of those for sure. As far as deleting table rows manually in response to UI, for some reason I was under the impression that you had to update the data source And manually delete the rows. Would I simply just update the data source in the contextual action and then call tableView.beginUpdates(), tableview.endUpdates() afterward?

Comment: You put table view manipulations (adding, deleting, reloading rows) between `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` to have the table animate the changes without reloading everything. Using observers to trigger UI manipulations based on data changes definitely isn't mandatory, it was just a suggestion.

Comment: I understand. Also, setting handler(true) was the solution! Everything works as expected now. Thanks!